# How to use command line argument in GNU make?

Tags: makefile

For example, I have 10 source files named `ex1.c`, `ex2.c`, `ex3.c`....`ex10.c` and maybe more in the future.

Is it possible that I can use commandline argument as a variable in GNU Make so that when I want to compile `ex1.c`, I can type in `make 1`. If I want to compile `ex10.c`, I can type in `make 10`. And I don't need to add more lines to `makefile` when I add more sources like `ex100.c` later.

Comment: Create a sample shell/command line script

Comment: You should be able to do `make ex1` and `make ex10` and `make ex100` with only two more letters typing; this is orthodox and requires no special rules in the `makefile`.  Clearly, if you use a longer name (`make example-10`), there is a little more to type, but mildly debatable whether it is really worthwhile.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't strike me as a good idea, but yes, you can do it.

To build object files (e.g. `ex3.o`):

```
%: ex%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o ex$*.o
```

To build executables (e.g.`ex3`):

```
%: ex%.c
    $(CC) $< -o ex$*
```